# Como editar o HTML e o CSS do WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Pessoal já procurei em todos os lugares onde posso ta fazendo a edição do CSS e do HTML em um site do WordPress e nao estou achando... alguém poderia me ajudar ou manda um link ta difícil.

Answer (score 0):

Até onde eu sei e pela experiência que eu tive você tem que ou criar ou editar um tema pronto e em seguida instalar o tema no painel do WordPress. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/